# How to use Dense_rank() order by time but ignore duplicates from another colum?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a dataframe like this :

```
network|Value1|Value2|datetime
---------------------------------------
1      |A     |null  |2021-07-16 15:59:56.133
1      |B     |null  |2021-07-15 11:00:05.633
1      |B     |null  |2021-07-15 10:59:59.100
1      |C     |null  |2021-07-15 06:03:49.000
1      |null  |A     |2021-07-16 15:59:56.133
1      |null  |B     |2021-07-16 14:45:00.309
1      |null  |C     |2021-07-16 09:19:26.580
```

I want to create two ranks:

1. for each network, I want to rank [Value1] by datetime desc
2. for each network, I want to rank [Value2] by datetime desc

But for each ranks, I don't want to count duplicates [Value1] or [Value2]

The expected outcome should be:

```
network|Value1|Value2|datetime                |rank_Value1 |rank_Value2
-------------------------------------------------------------
1      |A     |null  |2021-07-16 15:59:56.133 |1           |null  
1      |B     |null  |2021-07-15 11:00:05.633 |2           |null  
1      |B     |null  |2021-07-15 10:59:59.100 |2           |null  
1      |C     |null  |2021-07-15 06:03:49.000 |3           |null  
1      |null  |A     |2021-07-16 15:59:56.133 |null        |1
1      |null  |B     |2021-07-16 14:45:00.309 |null        |2
1      |null  |C     |2021-07-16 09:19:26.580 |null        |3
```

Since I want the rank to be the same when [Value] is duplicated and I want the rank to be incremented 1 by 1, I use DENSE_RANK() for that and I tried this:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN Value1 is null THEN NULL ELSE DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY network, CASE WHEN Value1 is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END order by datetime desc) END as rank_Value1,
    CASE WHEN Value2 is null THEN NULL ELSE DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY network, CASE WHEN Value2 is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END order by datetime desc) END as rank_Value2 
FROM df
```

But the outcome is as followed :

```
network|Value1|Value2|datetime                |rank_Value1 |rank_Value2
-------------------------------------------------------------
1      |A     |null  |2021-07-16 15:59:56.133 |1           |null  
1      |B     |null  |2021-07-15 11:00:05.633 |2           |null  
1      |B     |null  |2021-07-15 10:59:59.100 |3           |null  
1      |C     |null  |2021-07-15 06:03:49.000 |4           |null  
1      |null  |A     |2021-07-16 15:59:56.133 |null        |1
1      |null  |B     |2021-07-16 14:45:00.309 |null        |2
1      |null  |C     |2021-07-16 09:19:26.580 |null        |3
```

I feel like I am almost there but I don't know how to do this...
I am not comfortable with TSQL so if someone can help me, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: What rank would another row with a value of `A` for `Value1` at the "end" of your data have? `1` because that's the rank of the other row?

Comment: You say you want your rank determined by datetime BUT... it appears that `value1` (in your first scenario) is really your `ORDER BY`, not datetime. Switching your ORDER BY would give you the results you are after. Perhaps it's just your sample data lacking though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading through the lines here, but I suspect this is a gaps and island problem. If so, then I think this might be what you are after:

```sql
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,'A   ',null,CONVERT(datetime,'2021-07-16T15:59:56.133')),
                (1,'B   ',null,CONVERT(datetime,'2021-07-15T11:00:05.633')),
                (1,'B   ',null,CONVERT(datetime,'2021-07-15T10:59:59.100')),
                (1,'C   ',null,CONVERT(datetime,'2021-07-15T06:03:49.000')),
                (1,null,'A   ',CONVERT(datetime,'2021-07-16T15:59:56.133')),
                (1,null,'B   ',CONVERT(datetime,'2021-07-16T14:45:00.309')),
                (1,null,'C   ',CONVERT(datetime,'2021-07-16T09:19:26.580')))V(network,Value1,Value2,datetime)),
Grps AS(
    SELECT network,
           Value1,
           Value2,
           datetime,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY network ORDER BY datetime) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY network, Value1 ORDER BY datetime) AS Group1,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY network ORDER BY datetime) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY network, Value2 ORDER BY datetime) AS Group2
    FROM YourTable)
SELECT network,
       Value1,
       Value2,
       datetime,
       CASE WHEN Value1 IS NOT NULL THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY network, CASE WHEN Value1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY group1 DESC) END AS rank_Value1,
       CASE WHEN Value2 IS NOT NULL THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY network, CASE WHEN Value2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY group2 DESC) END AS rank_Value2
FROM Grps
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Value1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
         datetime DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about measuring the change in values?

```
SELECT df.*,
       (CASE WHEN value1 IS NOT NULL
             THEN SUM(CASE WHEN next_value_1 = value1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY datetime)
        END),
       (CASE WHEN value2 IS NOT NULL
             THEN SUM(CASE WHEN next_value_1 = value2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY datetime)
        END)
FROM (SELECT df.*,
             LEAD(value1) OVER (ORDER BY datetime) as as next_value1,
             LEAD(value2) OVER (ORDER BY datetime) as as next_value2
      FROM df
     ) df;
```

Note that in your sample data, the `value1`s and `value2`s are not interleaved.  The above assumes that is the case.  Otherwise, you need the `(case)` expression to separate out the rows with each value in the partitioning clauses.